Generalized Bernoulli Polynomial Difference Formula

For integers $m \geq 1, n \geq 1$ and complex numbers $a$, I want to prove
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(a+k)^{n-1}=\frac{B_n(a+m)-B_n(a)}{n},
$$
where $B_n$ are the Bernoulli Polynomials.

This is the generalized version of
$$
B_n(a+1)-B_n(a)=na^{n-1}.
$$
I proved this the following way:
Proof.$\,$ Taking Taylor series on both sides of the obvious identity
$$
\frac{z e^{(a+1) z}}{e^z-1}-\frac{z e^{a z}}{e^z-1}=z e^{a z},
$$
we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n(a+1)-B_n(a)}{n!} z^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} z^{n+1},
$$
and the assertion follows by comparison of coefficients.

However, I find it difficult to apply this to the general version $B_n(a+m)$. Therefore I tried to use
$$
\zeta(-n, a) = -\frac{B_{n+1}(a)}{n+1}
$$
and the identity
$$
\zeta(s, a)=\frac{1}{a^s}+\zeta(s, a+1)
$$
and this also gives the difference formula but not the generalized one (at least I cannot perform it).
Any hints on how to attack this one?

The EGF of Bernoulli polynomials is
$$\frac{z\exp(az)}{\exp(z)-1} =
\sum_{n\ge 0} B_n(a) \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$
We seek to show that with $m,n\ge 1$ and $a$ complex
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (a+k)^{n-1}
= \frac{1}{n} (B_n(a+m)-B_n(a)).$$
The LHS is
$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \exp((a+k)z)
= (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \exp(az) \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \exp(kz)
\\ = (n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \exp(az)
\frac{\exp(mz)-1}{\exp(z)-1}
= \frac{1}{n} n! [z^n] z \exp(az)
\frac{\exp(mz)-1}{\exp(z)-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{n} n! [z^n] z
\frac{\exp((a+m)z)-\exp(az)}{\exp(z)-1}
\\ = \frac{1}{n}
\left[ n! [z^n] \frac{z\exp((a+m)z)}{\exp(z)-1}
- n! [z^n]  \frac{z\exp(az)}{\exp(z)-1} \right].$$
This is the claim.
